# Python TCP packets getting mixed

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have a multiplayer game written in python and uses TCP, So when I send two packets at the same time they get mixed up example if I send "Hello there" and "man" the client receives "hello thereman".

What should I do to prevent them from getting mixed?

Comment: There is no corruption here. There is only coalescing of TCP segments, which TCP can do at any time. It's a byte-stream protocol, not a messaging protocol.

Comment: There is no 'mixing' either. Only coalescing.

Comment: well that's what I meant 'coalescing'.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question explains clearly a problem one might encounter when beginning with TCP streams; both the question and answer are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way TCP works.  It is a byte stream.  It is not message-based.

Consider if you write "Hello there" and "man" to a file.  If you read the file, you see "hello thereman".  A socket works the same way.

If you want to make sense of the byte stream, you need other information.  For example, add line feeds to the stream to indicate end of line.  For a binary file, include data structures such as "2-byte length (big-endian) followed by <length> bytes of data" so you can read the stream and break it into decipherable messages.

Note that socket methods `send()` and `recv()` must have their return values checked.  `recv(1024)` for example can return `''` (socket closed) or 1-1024 bytes of data.  The size is a *maximum* to be returned.  `send()` can send less than requested and you'll have to re-send the part that didn't send (or use `sendall()` in the first place).

Or, use a framework that does all this for you...

Comment: What about UDP? Does it mix packets aswell?

Comment: @Jesus711 TCP doesn't mix packets.  You get the data in the same order, but there are no message-boundaries unless you implement a protocol on top of it.  UDP *is* message-based, but delivery and delivery order are not guaranteed.  In TCP, you have to parse the stream for your messages.  In UDP, you have to collect the packets and order them yourself, and request re-transmission of missing ones (if you care).